# unexpected unindent, no lo localizo

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo un error de indentación. Revise el código y no localizo ninguno. También me asegure de no estar mezclando espacios con tabs pero aun así el error continua.

El error:

```
 File "c:\Users\Juan José\Documents\trabajos colegio\python\proyecto\db.py", line 51
def actualizar(id,datos):^
```

El código:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def cerrar():
    db.close()

def conectar():
    global db
    db = sqlite3.connect("usuarios.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE DATOSUSUARIOS (
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            NOMBRE VARCHAR(20), 
            APELLIDOS VARCHAR(20),
            CONTRASEÑA VARCHAR(20),
            DIRECCION VARCHAR(20)
            )
        ''')
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("La base de datos ya existe", "la base de datos a la que se esta tratando de conectar ya existe, conexion realizada exitosamente")
    db.commit()
    
    
def crear(data):
    try:
        sql = ''' INSERT INTO DATOSUSUARIOS (NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, CONTRASEÑA, DIRECCION)
                VALUES(?,?,?,?) '''
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        db.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Exito","el registro fue insertado exitosamente")

    except NameError:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", '''No hay ninguna base de datos
         asociada. Para comenzar a manipular la base de datos primero
          debe conectarse a esta desde el menú BBDD'''
          )

def leer(id):
    try:    
        sql = ''' SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, CONTRASEÑA, DIRECCION FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID= {} '''.format(id)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        db.commit()
        return data

def actualizar(id,datos):
    try:
        sql = "UPDATE DATOSUSUARIOS SET (NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, CONTRASEÑA, DIRECCION) VALUES(?,?,?,?) WHERE ID = {}".format(id)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, datos)
        db.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Exito","el registro fue actualizado exitosamente")
    except:
        pass

def eliminar(id):
    try:
        sql = '''DELETE FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID={}'''.format(id)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Solo has pegado la linea que te arroja el error, pero no pones el error. En fin, antes de esa linea (`51`) tienes un `try` sin terminar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error esta en el `try` sin `except`. Asi lucia antes:

```
def leer(id):
    try:
        sql = ''' SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, CONTRASEÑA, DIRECCION FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID= {} '''.format(id)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        db.commit()
        return data


def actualizar(id, datos):
    try:
```

Como el `try` no está completo, Python se encuentra con `def actualizar` cuando está esperando un `except`, así:

```
def leer(id):
    try:
        sql = ''' SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, CONTRASEÑA, DIRECCION FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID= {} '''.format(id)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        db.commit()
        return data
    except SomeException:
        do_something


def actualizar(id, datos):
    try:
```

Nota: este es sólo un ejemplo de como podría escribirse. El código final debe reflejar los requerimientos del problema original.